# How to configure Serverless Google Cloud Function to retry if fail?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, serverless

How to add `retry` attribute like the command using serverless?

```sh
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --retry
```

Take a look my `serverless.yml` file:

```
service: myService

provider:
  name: google
  stage: prod
  runtime: nodejs8
  region: us-central1
  project: my-project
  credentials: my-credentials.json

plugins:
  - serverless-google-cloudfunctions

functions:
  first:
    handler: myFunction
    events:
      - event:
          eventType: providers/cloud.pubsub/eventTypes/topic.publish
          resource: my-topic-name
```

Comment: What is the structure of this YAML file?  What might it be passed into?  What technology wants this YAML as input and how is it used?

Comment: @kolban My YAML is exactly like that.